# Alternative of "LIKE" operator in natively compiled stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I had used "LIKE" operator in many places of my existing stored procedures. Now, When I am doing native compilation.  At the compilation it gives me the error that "LIKE" operator is not supported.

Also I checked the list of supported operations for stored procedures at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn452279(v=sql.120).aspx

But I do not find any alternative of "LIKE" operator. So, please help me on this.

Here is the error I am getting :

[image]

Please update here if a newer version of SQL server also has such facility. So, can be helpful for others.

Comment: Edit your question and add your code.

Comment: like I written code 

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE EmpName LIKE '%SKU%'

Comment: You obiviously do something wrong there, but without knowing your **FULL** example, which would fail, we can't really help you. Only alternative I can think if would be using `CHARINDEX()`

Comment: CHARINDEX() is also not supported. Please check the link that I given.

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja: Can you please show us your code ?

Comment: Reading [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1465401/like-operator-support-in-natively-compiled-stored-procedures) it is clear that it is not supported... yet. They probably will in the future, it's apparantly "high on the list".